# Select json object based on key value pair

Tags: javascript, json, select, e4x

This might be a noob question, but I'm wondering if there's a way to select a json object without having to loop through key value pairs. I've done similar things with e4x, but I'm not sure how to do it syntactically for js. For example

```
 var data =   { "objects":[
                {"foo":"x","bar":"a"},
                {"foo":"y","bar":"b"}
              ]}
```

So instead of a for loop, some way to declare

```
 var someObject = data.objects[where objects.foo == x]
```

Comment: That's not JSON, that's object literal notation.

Comment: You are incorrect. JSON is a subset of Object Literal notation, and in fact requires identifiers in value pairs to be strings only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do that w/o **manually** iterate over data, but some code should iterate over object anyway (so doesn't expect lightning speed on rather large objects).

There's a library for that: [jsonpath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)

Comment: Ugh. I dislike depending on libraries. No pure way, eh? Guess I'm looping.

Comment: Then write it by yourself. Nothing special. Ah, you may take `findBy` from here: http://travian.kirilloid.ru/js/array.js

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked two years ago before [jsonQ](https://github.com/s-yadav/jsonQ/). jsonQ allows us to write code to find siblings, traverse trees etc. without having to write a bunch of loops inside loops. While the question wanted a way to find it in native JS, I think my 2-year-old question is a bit naive now. I was really looking for a library like jsonQ to avoid writing a bunch of ugly loops (though I could do the work myself).

Answer (score 0):

I was searching and just found this: https://github.com/lloyd/JSONSelect. I haven't tried it yet but it seems to be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but may this answer can help someone.

To select an item from list, you can use Javascript *filter* function:

```
var data = { "objects":[
                   {"foo":"x","bar":"a"},
                   {"foo":"y","bar":"b"}
                ]}

var someobject = filterObject('x');

function filterObject(fooValue) {
    return data.objects.filter(function(item) {
        return item.foo == fooValue;
    }
}
```